# RDLC report in WPF/MVVM application. how to display external images

Tags: wpf, image, external, rdlc

Im trying to run a RDLC report from a WPF/MVVM application, and save it into a folder. 
Report contains an external image, whose source is set by a dataset field passed to report (="file:\" + First(Fields!LOGO.Value, "DS_LOGO")).
This is the code I used to run report

```
Dim lr As New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport
lr.ReportPath="\\remoteServer\MyApp\reports\rdlc\TEST.rdlc"
lr.DataSources.Clear()
For Each dt As DataTable In ds.Tables
   lr.DataSources.Add(New Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource(dt.TableName, dt))   'DS_LOGO
Next

Dim PathDoc = "\\remoteServer\MyApp\reports\pdf\TEST.pdf"

Try
 lr.EnableExternalImages = True
 lr.Refresh()

 Dim bytes = lr.Render("PDF", "")

 Using fs As New System.IO.FileStream(PathDoc, System.IO.FileMode.Create)
      fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
      fs.Close()
 End Using
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

In the output report the external image is not shown, and the debug produces thees error messages

```
Warning: Le immagini con riferimenti a URL esterni non verranno visualizzate se il report viene pubblicato in un server di report senza un account UnattendedExecutionAccount o se per le immagini di destinazione non è consentito l'accesso anonimo. (rsWarningFetchingExternalImages)
Warning: Il valore della proprietà MIMEType per l'oggetto ‘Image1’ di tipo image è “application/octet-stream”, che non è una proprietà MIMEType valida. (rsInvalidMIMEType)
Warning: Il valore della proprietà ImageData per l'oggetto ‘Image1’ di tipo image è “”, che non è una proprietà ImageData valida. (rsInvalidExternalImageProperty)
```

I tried to run the report from a Web application, and it works.
how must i set up my WPF for this to work? thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting `lr.EnableExternalImages = False` ? Translating the error messages gave me the impression that the data table contains some images and the report writer simply can't link the PDF to such a source.

Comment: I think it must depend on some web server configuration. as I said, report works if it is launched from an ASP.NET application.
Anyway, I tried to set EnableExternalImages to False, and I got this message

'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll'
'report TEST contains external images. property EnableExternalImages is not set'